# I'm having trouble saving the data inside a span tag in a variable and then entering it in another field in the same form using selenium and python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tags

I need help with an error when executing a code with selenium in python, where I need to extract some values hosted in a span tag, I have proceeded to save the values in some variables called "cap1, cap2 and cap3". Subsequently I must enter in another field within the web form those values that were saved in the variables mentioned above, when I send the values to that field using send_keys it shows me this data:

```
 [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c89eac54b3083cd46252ddcfaa763150", element="51cb8aa0-f83c-4e9b-8b60-eb660d6ba102")>]
```

could someone help me with that, it could be that the value I am extracting in the variables is not the correct one, it is worth noting that I used this code:

```
cap1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[9]/div/div/span[1]")
```

To extract the value and store it in the variable Should I use another way to extract the value and store it in the variable?

what I really want is to extract a numerical value that is displayed on the web, save it in a variable and then enter it in a field within a form on the same web.

Comment: .text if you mean just the string values inside that selenium element.

Answer (score 0):

To extract any value from a span tag using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491), once you identify the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) you need to use the [*get_attribute()*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method along with the desired attribute or property as follows:

```
cap1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[9]/div/div/span[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Incase of extracting the text you can also use the *text* attribute as follows:

```
cap1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[9]/div/div/span[1]").text
```